# Shutdown spark structured streaming gracefully

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

There is a way to enable graceful shutdown of spark streaming by setting property `spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown` to true and then kill the process with `kill -SIGTERM` command. However I don't see such option available for structured streaming (SQLContext.scala).

Is the shutdown process different in structured streaming? Or is it simply not implemented yet?

Comment: We had a similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59310665/how-to-stop-a-notebook-streaming-job-gracefully/59760474#59760474)  recently and solved it by using the filesystem to stop the streaming job gracefully

Answer (score 5):

This feature is not implemented yet. But the write ahead logs of spark structured steaming claims to recover state and offsets without any issues.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that if I shut down a Spark Structured Streaming application launched through spark-submit command using a kill command, despite not having a "graceful shutdown", no data will be lost?

Comment: @AnderMurilloZohn yes

Answer (score 0):

This Feature is not implemented yet and will also give you duplicates if you kill the job from the resource Manager while the batch is running.

Corrected: The duplicates will only be in the output directory, Write ahead logs handle everything beautifully; you don't need to worry about anything. Feel free to kill it any time.

Comment: According to another answer there shouldn't be issues due write-ahead logs feature. Did you try to kill the process from command line? Does it produce duplicates too?

Comment: Depends on your definition of issue. Technically duplicates are not considered an issue because you have at-least-once delivery guarantee anyway and duplicates don't violate that guarantee, i.e. you should be expecting duplicates anyway.

Comment: Yes, Correcting my old self here, You will not get duplicates the WAL stuff is so good in Spark it can handle any kill command. Go ahead and do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this github example code.

https://github.com/kali786516/FraudDetection/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/datamantra/spark/jobs/RealTimeFraudDetection/StructuredStreamingFraudDetection.scala#L76

https://github.com/kali786516/FraudDetection/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/datamantra/spark/GracefulShutdown.scala#L26